# How to get next day at a certain hour in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime, days

I need to check a date in PHP if it is bigger than the 00:00 hours of the next day.
At the first sight I tried to use

```
if($date_variable<strtotime('+1day')){
   return true;
}else{
   return false
}
```

But what it's doing is in fact adding to time() (24*60*60)

Is there any solution to that?

*P.S.: Im trying to avoid the use of date on +1day and backwards to UNIX without hours info*

Comment: Is $date_variable a DateTime object?

Comment: Are u using unix timestamp or y-m-d H-i-s format?

Comment: @Xfile Seems, a UNIX timestamp, as strtotime returns a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the accepted answer is now over three years old and since we got PHP5 and even now PHP7 we can do it much easier with the `DateTime` class. The `DateTime` class is a native PHP class. No further library is in need.

```
$oDateNow = new DateTime(); // Date now
$oDateTomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow midnight'); // Date tomorrow midnight

$bResult = $oDateNow < $oDateTomorrow ? true : false;
```

The `DateTime` class accepts all parameters the `strtotime()` function also accepts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if($date_variable<strtotime('midnight tomorrow')){
   return true;
}else{
   return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using mktime() like this :

```
if($date_variable<mktime(0,0,0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('Y')){
   return true;
}else{
   return false
}
```

Comment: Hell Yeah!
Thanks a lot dude. I had that feeling of "i have it in front of my eyes but I can't see it". I will use Nils solution just cause it's smaller code, but lot of thanks for the help.